# Select using MySQL shows Mysql::Result, not my value

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am trying to make a simple command line user authentication system in Ruby.
I am using MySQL to store user information.
I decided to store the passwords as MD5 hashes, mainly because it is simple.
I am not going for anything crazy secure at the moment, I just want it to work.
However when I use a select statement in Ruby to pull the hash out so I can compare it with a hash of whatever the user entered it does not come out in the same 32 character format!

When I use MySQL to select the hash I get:

```
 SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = 'admin';
 +----------------------------------+
 | password                         |
 +----------------------------------+
 | d456c1f6fa85ed2f6a26b15139c6ddc2 |
 +----------------------------------+
```

When I use Ruby however..

```
 con.query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = 'admin'")
 #<Mysql::Result:0x950b208>
```

I haven't ever really programmed anything before, and am really enjoying Ruby.
I have been googling this for two days now and can't seem to find anything.
I am sorry if this is a really easy fix, but I cant seem to find it anywhere.
I would also love suggestions about a better way to go about this little project! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have `FROM users` in one query and `FROM employee` in the other by the way (although that's not the problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to just process the results of the query.  The return value of `query` is a result set object:

```
rows = con.query("SELECT password FROM employee WHERE username = 'admin'")
rows.each do |row|
   puts row[0]
end
```

Comment: @Phrogz: That is a good point; it seems reasonable to assume unique user names. It would be a bit problematic otherwise.

Comment: @Phrogz: Based on the output of the `con.query` command, I think the original poster is using the `mysql` gem, which doesn't support calling `first` on the result set. For me, `con.query("...").fetch_row[0]` works, though. (It seems that using the `ruby-mysql` gem does allow you to call `first[0]`).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rows.map(&:password)
```

that should work too.